# WordPress Error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Warning: require_once(/home/tnckhinu/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions /comments.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tnckhinu/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/tnckhinu/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions /comments.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home/tnckhinu/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions.php on line 17

this is the error message I am getting from my wordpress site as I just installed new theme after that I got this error and now i can't even login to `wp-admin.php`.

> Note: I don't have C-panel access nor FTP.

Comment: It seems some error in your theme file which require a file which not included in the theme folder. If you have FTP then rename that theme folder and try

Comment: report to your host support , you need access ftp or cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deactivate theme.
You can deactivate it, by rename it's folder name.

And this error comes because some file is missing in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

This is file missing error. Put **comments.php** into the following function directory: `/home/tnckhinu/public_html/wp-content/themes/appointment/functions`.

Answer (score -1):

You need a comments.php, its required in every theme. Change your theme to something else and everything shoudl work. If you want to keep your current theme, ask the creator to fix it.